# Populate a DropDownBox in VB.NET from database but have custom display name

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

Ok, so I have no problem loading my ComboBoxes with data from my database and assigning it the correct ValueMember, but I need to concatenate *"user_last_name" & ", " & "user_first_name"* so it displays better information than just a username.  Hopefully this is just a simple fix, I

```
Private Sub loadMemberName()

    Dim memberSELECTSQLString As String =
        "SELECT * FROM user_tbl"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(memberSELECTSQLString, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "user_tbl")

    With memberComboBox
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("user_tbl")
        .DisplayMember = "user_username"
        .ValueMember = "user_id"
        .SelectedValue = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the name in your SQL statement?  SELECT user_first_name + ' ' + user_last_name AS user

Comment: I will post working code after my 6 hour new user grace period is up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate it in your sql and send back the alias, then reference the alias in your combo box

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_last_name, ', ', user_first_name) username FROM user_tbl
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_last_name, ', ', user_first_name) AS username FROM user_tbl
```

Comment: You need an AS userName to bind in .NET to the DisplayMember.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know the syntax to concatenate

```
select top 10 [docID] + ' ' + [textHash] as [userName], [docID] from docSVsys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub loadMemberName()

    Dim memberSELECTSQLString As String =
        "SELECT user_id, user_last_name + ', ' + user_first_name AS username FROM user_tbl"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(memberSELECTSQLString, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "user_tbl")

    With memberComboBox
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("user_tbl")
        .DisplayMember = "username"
        .ValueMember = "user_id"
        .SelectedValue = -1
    End With
End Sub
```